# For loop is changing the iterator and stopping after first iteration VBA

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop

I do a simple iteration through a range of columns to replace a "-" string with nothing.
However, it only does the first iteration and then exits the loop.
The code is the following:

```
For i = 2 To ultimo
    StrEx = Workbooks(custodio).Sheets(1).Range("A" & i).Value
    StrEx = Replace(StrEx, "-", """")
    Workbooks(custodio).Sheets(1).Range("A" & i).Value = StrEx
Next i
```

Where `ultimo` is the last row, `custodio` is the name of the workbook.
The `i` value changes after the first row inside the loop is executed, and if I hover over it, it throws a value of 454311[image]

Any idea?

Comment: I took out the Workbooks(custodio). part and just started the line with Sheets(1) and it worked for me. Not sure if that will help or VBA is just doing something odd to you

Comment: What value is `ultimo` giving you?

Comment: Is `ultimo` = `454310` or `454311`?  Is the hyphen in the cells really a hyphen (ASCII code `45`)?  There are other characters that look like a hyphen but have different character codes.

Comment: Two things ... why 4 quote marks for the empty string? And what happens if you either “dim i as integer” (which might generate an error if it is a redefinition) or chose a different variable name (eg n). I wonder if something else has declared i somewhere?

Comment: So to answer everyone. `ultimo` gives me 42 (as you can see the first `Debug.Print` instruction corresponds to the first value in intermediate. Yes, it is a hyphen. The 4 quote marks were a mistake (I'm used to set empty strings when telling a macro to write a formula on a range, so that's how it is represented), however it doesn't have anything to do with the i value. And lastly, the i value is not declared elsewhere, and it has the same error with another variable name. Furthermore, even though it was declared somewhere else, it should re-declare with `i = 2` at the beginning of the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. there is no need to retrieve the workbook and the sheet on each iteration. Faster to save the worksheet as a variable before you enter the loop
2. `i` needs to be declared as `Long` (a worksheet can have 1048576 rows and `Integer` is not enough)
3. There is no need to concatenate `"A"` every time. You could simply use column 1
4. you could save the cell you read/write so you don't have to retrieve it twice. Even better you could use a `With` construct

Try this code which addresses the above:

```
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim i As Long

Set sht = Workbooks(custodio).Sheets(1)
For i = 2 To ultimo
    With sht.Cells(i, 1) 'Instead of sht.Range("A" & i)
        .Value2 = Replace(.Value2, "-", """")
    End With
Next i
```

I don't know why you would get `i` changed as in your question but I would like to see you test this code and see if it works

Comment: Hi Christian, yes it works this way and I know a couple of workarounds for the problem (like doing the replace on Excel range and just using VBA to insert the formula as well). I'm marking this as a solution because it is a different method of achieving the same result, however my question was not answered in full, still don't know why the weird behavior on that. 
About your observations, thank you, the code is made for someone else to read it as well so I try not to do a lot of shortening so he can read it while he's still learning.

Comment: @CarlosCasio Yes, I agree. Hence, my last paragraph. I suspected that your issue might be related to retrieving some of those objects every time but I obviously needed to narrow it down first. It is very difficult to pinpoint the exact line that caused the issue from my end as I cannot test. But you can now try to replace things step by step and find the exact line that is causing the issue. BTW, the whole range can be first read into an array, then the logic works on the array and finally the whole array can be written back in one block. The speed improvement can be big for large datasets.